# Sync pulse from PC

Tags: microcontroller, communication, linux

Can anyone suggest a way that I can send or detect short pulses between a microcontroller and an old laptop with limited I/O functionality. I need to do this every 5-10 sec.

The laptop doesn't have serial or parallel ports, just a few USB ports, acard reader, and audio i/o. (It;s an Acer Aspire 3100).

I tried to send pulse with keyboard LEDs (using Ioctl calls) but it seems to be noisy.

Comment: And your question is.....?

Comment: What is easiest and fastest way to do it? :)

Comment: USB to TTL converter would be one way.

Comment: Don't have time to order one.

Comment: how much time have you got? The hardware solution may need various op-amps and peak detector diodes etc if you use audio port as Spehro suggests, and that may take you hours to come up with the circuit and to prototype it enough that it works. Maybe hack up a USB cable, and use it's 5V line from the USB port and access the USB ports at a driver-level in software and enable/disable them to turn the 5V output on/off as the signal?? Would depend on the motherboard design and if it allows USB power suspension etc.

Comment: If you are using windows, it seems there is a USB Hub driver SDK you can use to program that On/off functionality, http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/147369-usb-selective-suspend-turn-off.html

Comment: @KyranF I'm not sure that suspending the USB device kills the 5V power line. I think all it does is inform the device to go into a low power mode (the device is responsible for reducing its own power consumption) and then the hub stops talking to the device until it is ready to resume. If it killed the power then the device would have to re-enumerate when the power was restored which wouldn't be the same behaviour as suspend mode.

Comment: And from window's online documents https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn449739%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @TomCarpenter according to the documents it's implemented at a hardware level, I think it actually does fully cut off power. It is not allowed to do so until the USB device has indicated that it is in "idle" state though

Comment: @TomCarpenter It is a little ambiguous as to if the hardware layer actually does a full power-down sequence, disabling the 5V line to that port. The drivers are meant to do that, but it's up to the hardware (the particular motherboard) to actually implement it. Either way this guy is going to have a long night ahead trying to implement something like this! I think Linux would be far easier, like 1 line in bash script, to get the same result lol (assuming hardware supports power-off)

Comment: Well it seems that you cannot reliably control USB power supply to ports, unless you are very lucky with what hardware you have.

Comment: @KyranF Devices allowed to draw up to 500uA when in suspend mode, so there must still be 5V otherwise they couldn't draw any power. I've just tried with my laptop and when I put it to sleep, there is still 5V from the USB port. I was looking through the USB2 spec and can't find anything concrete.

Comment: @TomCarpenter yeah after digging further I can't find any useful information on the hardware layer, most documents just say "sends request to driver" to suspend the power for that port, but as you say it still seems to remain powered to some extent. The USB standard says that when a device says it's "idle" it must be able to then go into "power down" state for the purpose of this suspend feature

Comment: What is "noisy" about the keyboard?  Do you need exact timing?  If so, you're going to be pretty unhappy with Windows, as well as with USB devices, especially the converters.

Answer (score 1):

Buy a USB to serial cable (any computer store should have them for $15 +/-) and convert the RS-232 data output to your microcontroller's logic level with a transistor, diode and a couple resistors.

You might be able to do something similar with the audio output directly (detect the AC with volume set to max), but I suspect it would be more jittery.

Comment: Shipping would take to long. I need it working by tomorrow.

Comment: Then do it with the audio output sa Spehro suggested.

Comment: Would it be more reliable to count pulses generated from audio card or to use frequency to voltage converter?

Comment: You have not mentioned any kind of specs. The simplest method would be to turn a tone off and on and detect the presence of AC at the output. It can be made reliable, but the sync may not be all that accurate in terms of milliseconds.

Comment: Using just an audio signal. a diode and RC filtering as needed, you can get output within 1 cycle. If you can tolerate pulses then a diode is all you need and go/stop is as fat a an audio cycle period. If you need DC when on you  can add an RC filter with attendant decay time on turnoff. Knowing your spec help heaps. | An LDR or phototransistor against the screen allows display based signalling. You can do N of these. Microphone in allows tone in.